# I still don't understand how to configure external applications to open files

Tags: firefox, kde, flatpak

Firefox 105.0.1 (Flatpak)
Kubuntu 22.04

Default application in KDE for application/pdf is Okular (which works fine).
In Firefox, application/pdf is set to "Always ask".

I click on a PDF link, and get a dialog, the file is identified as "Portable Document Format (PDF)" and I can "Open with Firefox", "Open with [System Handler (default)]" or "Save File". So far so good, everything as expected.

Choosing "Open with [System Handler (default)]" does nothing. The file is apparently downloaded, but nothing happens (and no message on terminal).

The dropdown list offers only "System Handler (default)" and "Other...". Selecting "Other..." brings up a new window with a big empty box saying "No applications found for "PDF document files", and a button "View All Applications". Clicking the button gives only a list of "Other Applications" where only "Firefox" appears. Nothing more. No way to search the filesystem, no way to specify Okular or `/usr/bin/okular`.

The `handlers.json` file in my profile contains an entry `"application/binary":{"action":2,"ask":true,"handlers":[{"name":"Okular","path":"/usr/bin/okular"}],"extensions":["pdf"]}`, if I copy the same but for `"application/pdf"`, nothing changes, Okular still doesn't appear and I can't open the file with Okular. I tried giving Firefox access to the whole host filesystem with Flatseal, but nothing changed either.

What is going on? Why is it always so difficult to set a specific external application for particular file types (you can guess it's not the first time I experience something similar)?

EDIT: Installing Firefox from a ppa (https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/) worked fine, although see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162742/where-does-firefox-get-the-default-applications-for-opening-files-from too. Since this still does not solve the issue for the flatpak version, I don't consider this an "answer", but it works for me (I never wanted the flatpak version to start with).

Comment: Have you tried installing Firefox as packages, rather than flatpack (which as you state, is isolated), from Mozilla? See https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/mozilla_team_firefox_next for Ubuntu installation

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, I haven't tried. I was annoyed enough by Firefox transitioning to snap (where system cursors didn't work) and then installing the flatpak version. I'll try a ppa (although probably not a beta version).

Comment: Yes, when Ubuntu switched to snap, which, like flatpack, includes all dependencies, I uninstalled snap completely, and either perform manual package install from terminal, or add the ppa, as in Mozilla, or use the Windows version, as for 7-Zip in wine. This also avoids delays in getting app updates, as Ubuntu is slow to update many apps. My experience is that they work as well or *better* than the snap version.